# linux open a usb device failed errno EACCES

Tags: linux, permissions, usb

I want to connect with a usb device on linux. and I use libusb to connect. but when I call usb_open(dev) ,it return NULL, find check the libusb source,in linux.c I find the implementaiton of usb_open.as

int usb_os_open(usb_dev_handle *dev)

{

```
char filename[PATH_MAX + 1];

snprintf(filename, sizeof(filename) - 1, "%s/%s/%s",
usb_path, dev->bus->dirname, dev->device->filename);

dev->fd = open(filename, O_RDWR);                                                      
if (dev->fd < 0) {
 dev->fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
 if (dev->fd < 0)
   USB_ERROR_STR(-errno, "failed to open %s: %s",
     filename, strerror(errno));
}

return 0;
```

}

so it failed when open, and errno is set EACCES. But I check the device permission like this:

crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 189, 139  8月 26 10:38 /dev/bus/usb/002/012

so , is there any other conditions limit to open the device?